# JQuery Select elements using wildcard (*)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to JQuery please help.
I need to select multiple elements knowing only part of Id:
eg:

```
<div id="element32422455">Some content</div>
<div id="element68475124">Some content</div>
<div id="element42352355">Some content</div>
```

Is is possible to select those elements using staff like this

```
$('#element*');
```

If you know any other good way to do it, please tell.

Comment: You can use the 'attribute starts with' selector: `$('[id^=element]')` Note however that it would be much quicker (and better practice) to give all those elements a common class and select by that, `$('.element')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it by using [`attribute starts with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/),

```
var elems = $('[id^=element]');
```

There is no need to use wild card selector at this context, it is actually called [`attribute contains selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/). And that will select the element though it has id like `"123213element12312"`

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9f96ooj2/)

Comment: thanks! it works for me